# How can I implement a proportional error control scheme with op amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, infrared, distance, error-correction

So I have an IR distance sensor that I would like to use to keep two wheels (with DC motors) travelling parallel to the wall beside them.

I have these proportional error control formulae to keep the wheels straight;
$$
V_1 = V_{nom} + k_p (d - d_{nom})
$$
$$
V_2 = V_{nom} - k_p (d - d_{nom})
$$
but how should I set up the op-amp circuits for these formulae?

Comment: It's easiest to do this in multiple parts- find the kp(d-dnom), then add or subtract that from Vnom. You may wish to separate out the kp so that only one resistor needs to be changed to modify the control loop gain.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Do I need two separate IR sensors for d and d_nom?

Comment: If d and dnom are the same numbers in each equation, no. If they're different you should use subscripts or some other means to distinguish one from the other.

Comment: No, d_nom is not a measurement, it's a constant representing the nominal distance that you would like the robot to maintain from the wall.  You could make it adjustable via a potentiometer.

Comment: @pericynthion okay thanks, so how could I use a voltage to represent this term (d-d_nom) using one IR sensor?

Comment: Well the voltage output from the IR sensor represents d.  You can generate d_nom with a potential divider (or a potentiometer, to make it adjustable).  You can configure an op amp as a "voltage subtractor" (also known as a "differential amplifier") to subtract d_nom from d.
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

Comment: @pericynthion how can I add the terms to obtain V_1 without a summing op amp (using single supply)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses only six components (3 resistor networks, 2 quad op-amps and a gain-setting resistor R5).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLZV64.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you add some description of how the various parts of this circuit work and how they correspond to the terms and operations in the equations?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I thought I'd let you figure this out a bit. There are really only a couple distinct building blocks here (maybe only one).

Comment: I'm not the OP, but ;)
OA1, OA4 OA5 are simple buffers to give the circuit a high-impedance input.  OA2 along with R1 and R2 inverts the voltage coming from NODE1.  OA3, R3, R4 and R5 form an inverting summing amplifier, thus the voltage at OA3's output is equal to k_p * (node1 - node2). (...)

Comment: ... Let's call that node at the output of OA3 "Vdiff".  The potential divider after OA5 sets the voltage at the noninverting inputs to OA7 and OA8 equal to (NODE3)/2.  OA7 gives NODE4 = ((NODE3)/2) - Vdiff.  OA6 inverts Vdiff prior to it reaching OA8, giving NODE5 = ((NODE3)/2) + Vdiff.

Thus, NODE1 = d (distance sensor), NODE2 = d_nom, NODE3 = 2 * V_nom, NODE4 = V_2 (inboard motor) and NODE5 = V_1 (outboard motor).

I'm not clear on the purpose of the R8/R9 divider, why not simply use V_nom directly?

OP will probably want to insert a power amp between NODE4/5 and the actual motor outputs.

Comment: @pericynthion The divider is optional - if you're willing to use Vnom/2 rather than Vnom, then OA5, R8, R9 can be eliminated and Vnom/2 input connected directly to the high-Z non-inverting inputs of OA7 and OA8.

Comment: But why do you want Vnom/2 at all?  The division by 2 is not in the original equation, is there something I'm missing about the adders?

Comment: There's a gain of 2 from the POV of the non-inverting input, so we need to divide it down to get back to 1.

Comment: Ah of course, that's easy to see if you imagine the other input is held at ground. Thanks.